# Chrome Extension Manifest permissions blocked

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I got sucked with this issues while trying to upgrade my extension on Chrome Store. I tried all recommended solutions without success. Can someone help please?[This is what I got from Chrome Store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFixm.png)

This is my Manifest file:

```
  {
    "name": "__MSG_appName__",
    "version": "{{version}}",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "__MSG_appDescription__",
    "icons": {
      "16": "images/icon-16.png",
      "19": "images/icon-19.png",
      "32": "images/icon-32.png",
      "38": "images/icon-38.png",
      "48": "images/icon-48.png",
      "64": "images/icon-64.png",
      "128": "images/icon-128.png"
    },
    "default_locale": "en",
    "background": {
      "scripts": [ ]
    },
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon-16.png",
        "19": "images/icon-19.png",
        "32": "images/icon-32.png",
        "38": "images/icon-38.png",
        "48": "images/icon-48.png",
        "64": "images/icon-64.png",
        "128": "images/icon-128.png"
      },
      "default_title": "..."
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "name": "main_scripts",
        "matches": [
          "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
        ],
        "css": []
        "run_at": "document_start",
        "all_frames": false
      }
    ],
    "permissions": [
      "activeTab",
      "contextMenus",
      "history",
      "storage",
      "management",
      "webRequest",
      "webRequestBlocking"
    ]
  }
```

I don't know if this could help. This is what I get in development environment:
[Error from chrome://extension 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDTJs.png),
 [Error from chrome://extension 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rtXL6.png)

Comment: Your extension can effectively access all URLs via its content script `"matches"` permissions. It's effectively the same as having those patterns in `"permissions"`. The recommended solution is `declarativeContent` API and *optional permissions*, see the documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm, Do you mean my Manifest file is wrong or is it related to the Background one? Also could you please give more details to help fix this? Because I did never face this before and just today I got this while trying to publish a new version.

Comment: It means Chrome WebStore has changed the policy on extensions that can access all URLs.

Comment: I am totally agree with this and I follow this https://developer.chrome.com/apps/permission_warnings to upgrade my `manifest.json` file but the issue still got unfixed. I can't figure what I miss.

Comment: My first comment describes the cause and solution. We're going in circles.